# Get data into gridview devexpress

Tags: devexpress, gridcontrol

In gridcontrol devexpress, I display "employee_id" column as  combobox. I want to fill data from EMPLOYEES table into "employee_id" column in gridcontrol devexpress. Thanks.

Comment: what platform? Win, ASP, WPF, SL?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you handle the [GridView.ShownEditor](http://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsBaseColumnView_ShownEditortopic) event. Within this event handler, you can obtain the currently displayed clone of the column editor, and filter its items. Here is some sample code:

```
private void gridView_ShownEditor(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    GridView view = (GridView)sender;
    if (view.FocusedColumn != employee_id) return;
    ComboBoxEdit editor = (ComboBoxEdit)view.ActiveEditor;       
    // Here bind the editor DataSource and ValueMember and 
       Display member to employee_id
}
```

Other way as:
Ref: [How to bind dataset with different values to repository combobox in runtime](http://community.devexpress.com/forums/t/89945.aspx)

```
RepositoryItemComboBox combo = new RepositoryItemComboBox();
            combo.Items.AddRange(new string[{values});
            gridControl1.RepositoryItems.Add(combo);
            gridView1.Columns["Criteria"].ColumnEdit = combo;
```

Ref:
 [How to populate the RepositoryItemCheckedComboBox with item based on the selection    made in another cell](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q220234.aspx)
[combobox in gridcontrol](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q307517.aspx)
[Column Value List](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/p/Q96215.aspx)